# Mongoose not returning value

Tags: mongoose

The function GetByName works because the results are printing to console correctly but I am not returning the value. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
supportDoc.tagId = GetByName(item.tagName); <-- returns undefined


function GetByName(name) {
model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name : name}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
        console.log('Not Found')
    } else {
        console.log(result._id);
        return (result._id)
    };
});
```

UPDATE:

Copied victorkohl's suggestion, still error.

The value is passing but still getting error. Here is intellisense, console and "foreign key" property.

[image]

**SOLVED:**

victorkohl was correct, I just had to put the function call to GetByName at the end and have the save method inside it.

```
   model.Shared_SupportDoc.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
                var supportDocs = require('../../data/_seed/support/supportDocs.json');
                if (collection.length === 0) {
                    supportDocs.forEach(function (item) {
                        ....
                        supportDoc.icon = item.icon;
                        supportDoc.likeCount = item.likeCount || 7;
            GetByName(item.category, function(tagId) {
                supportDoc.categoryId = tagId;
                supportDoc.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(supportDoc.categoryId)
                        console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Support Doc Seed Complete');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a synchronous task using an asynchronous method. The function passed on `.exec()` is executed asynchronously and, therefore, your function GetByName returns BEFORE that function executes (without a value, thus the `undefined` result).

You should make the GetByName function also run asynchronously, for instance:

```
GetByName(item.tagName, function(tagId) {
    supportDoc.tagId = tagId;
});


function GetByName(name, next) {
    model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name : name}).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (!result) {
            console.log('Not Found');
            next();
        } else {
            console.log(result._id);
            next(result._id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if (result.length === 0) { ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null. name parameter has no value in function

Comment: fixed it. when no results are found, `result` have no method `length`